# Php function in echo? Is it possible?

Tags: php

Hi I have a special problem ... I have three values from database.

```
Value1 is 1 or 0
Value2 is again 1 or 0
Value3 is remaining time like (24 hours left, 23, ...)
```

There values are saved in variables:

```
$value1
$value2
$value3
```

These values change from DB  on every load from webpage. I have these values also inside echo""; The php function is already like:

```
echo"text text text .................
"Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 . ""
..................;
```

I need a function that says different things like

```
if (value1=0)
echo "Only text"
else
echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 . "";
```

this to be in another echo function from first example so in my way it looks like this:

```
*Some function*
echo"if (value1=0)
echo "Only text"
else
echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 . """; // two echo closing
```

But it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.How to solve this? thank you.

Comment: i really think you should format your question better.

Comment: Your aim is extremely unclear. Can you add some code showing your expected output, exactly as the browser should receive it?

Comment: Based on your comments and the question I have the impression you have a wrong idea of how `echo` works and your problem in general. You **cannot** have a function inside `echo`. Echo is just for printing text. You have to decide which text you want to print *before* you use echo. That means you put the `echo` statement *inside* an `if-else` clause, not vice versa.

Comment: I think you are searching for eval();

Answer (score 11):

Echo is saying to output whatever you type. Saying to output "echo" actually means to display the word "echo". There's no reason to output an output... you already output it!

I think what you want is something more like:

```
if($value1 == 0){
    echo "Only text";
} else {
    echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second piece of code looks fine. Having multiple `echo` statements is not a problem, and using `if...else` to choose one is perfectly reasonable.

If you have to use just one for some reason, you can use the `(...) ? ... : ...` ternary operator.

```
echo (value1 == 0) ? 'Only text' : "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 . """;
```

Comment: It does not work: *Some function*
echo"if (value1==0)
echo "Only text"
else
echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 . """; When i have function in echo is it enough to have one " or double "" plus anything else?

Comment: It doesn't work 'cause you added stuff to it. You put an `echo` in front, which means you're trying to literally display the PHP code on the page. The exact code I wrote is what will work.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `value1==0`. Basically `=` means you assign the value `0` into the variable `value1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function chVal($value1, $value2) {
    if ($value1 == 0) {
        echo "Only text";
    } else {
        echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . " and Value 2 is:" . $value2;
    }
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

**EDIT**: I think I get what you mean.

```
function chVal ($val) {
    if ($val == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
if ($value1) {
    echo "Value 1 is:" . $value1 . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Only Text\n";
}

if ($value2) {
    echo "Value 2 is:" . $value2 . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Only Text\n";
}
```

Comment: `if (condition) return true;`? Really?

Comment: @Platinum Azure, what the problem with that?

Comment: Why so complicated? `chVal($value2)` is the same as `$value2 == 0`. There is really no benefit to create an extra function here. And even the function would be better written as `function chVal($val){ return ($val == 0)};`. What Platinum means is that `if (condition) return true` is the same as `return (condition)`.

Comment: @Platinum Yea, was about to say, `if (...) return true; else return false;` irks me every time. @Ruel It's far easier, clearer and shorter to write `function chVal ($val) { return $val == 0; }`

Comment: Just realized, 0 == false, so why not directly make it a condition. :)

Comment: That is not that case :-D ok again imagine only one variable => $value - it has 1 or 0 and i need to check if 1 displays something and if 0 display something else - in fifferent colors ... This code is almost ok: $value = ($value == 0 ? 'Only Text' : "Value 1 is:$value1 and value2 is: $value2");

echo "echo \"$value\"";
But i need different colors for text ...

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
<?php
$value1=0;
$value2=1;
echo ($value1==0) ? "value 1 is :".$value1." and value 2 is ".$value2 : "only text";
?>
```

Comment: i will try this will answer here my results :-)

Comment: $value1 and $value2 are defined earlier in code and they need to be called in another echo function of different if :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like this:

```
echo "Value 1 : ".func1($value1)." - Value 2 : ".func2($value2)." - Value 3 : ".func3($value3);
```

then you may have 3 functions or 1 depending on how complex is your logic.

```
function func1($value){
 if ($value == 0) return " zero ";
 else return " else ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

I think you're looking to display the PHP code itself: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

```
<?php
   highlight_string('
      function chkValue($value1,$value2) {
        if($value1 == 0) {
           echo "Only Text<br />";
        } else {
           echo "Value 1 is: ".$value1." and Value 2 is: ".$value2."<br />";
        }
       }
   ');
?>
```

Comment: Yes and how to put this function to another echo all of it without problems with ""

Comment: do you want to print the function itself?

Comment: I just need Only Text OR Value 1 is: (etc) printed in another echo "" so how to put this function to another echo ...

Comment: I dont need somehow defined $value2 ... So I will try again ... It code there is some function with echo "" <= in this echo I need implemented display text if value1 is 1 or value is 0 nothing more other variables are not important now i am just adding them there in another variant

Comment: So it will looks like: echo "text text text "if($value1 == 0) {echo "Only Text<br />"} else {echo "Value 1 is: ".$value1." and Value 2 is: ".$value2."<br />";}"txt text text"; But I am doing something wrong it hs blank page only ...

Comment: Display would be: text text text Only text text text text OR text text text Value 1 is: 1 and Value 2 is 20 - this not have to be values 1 or 2 just some random text again ...

Comment: dude you got me, I don't know what you want. Sorry, please try to re-write your question so we can better understand. Try Google translate http://translate.google.com/#

Answer (score 1):

Probably in this way,

```
echo 'if (value1=0)
echo "Only text"
else
echo "Value 1 is:"' . $value1 . " and value 2 is:" . $value2 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what you're trying to achieve, but based on some of your other comments I'm beginning to suspect you want to echo PHP code:

```
$value = ($value == 0 ? 'Only Text' : "Value 1 is:$value1 and value2 is: $value2");

echo "echo \"$value\";";
```

#### update:

> Yes thats it! Working but I need different colors for the two texts :-) How to add there?

I'm assuming you're outputting the text to a browser, so something like this will work:

```
$value = '<span style="color:#'
  . ($value == 0 ? 'f00">Only Text' : "0f0\">Value 1 is: $value1 and value2 is:  $value2")
  . '</span>';

echo "echo \"$value\";";
```

Comment: Yes thats it! Working but I need different colors for the two texts :-) How to add there?

Comment: and las one how to change $value to int (not have digital numbers instead 50.74 will be 50 in result? Thank you :-)

Comment: @Hawgang Either cast your values to int: `$value1 = (int)$value;` or round them: `$value1 = round($value1);`

Comment: I have done it in selection thank you for your help you can close :-)

Comment: @Hawgang It's up to you to "close" this question by accepting an answer. If this answer solved your problem, click the check mark next to it to accept it.

Comment: SO no ... changing colors are not working - "Only Text" - should be red and "Value 1 is:" - blue and i cannot do it with your code :-(

Comment: If you want the second string to be blue, change `"0f0` to `"00f`.

Comment: it does not changing colors :-/ even when i change it

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ($value1 == 0)?'Yes':'No';
```